# Hover menu on UITabBar Item on iPhone

Tags: iphone, ios, cocoa-touch, uikit

I'm looking to implement a hover menu that is temporary and will automatically fade away (either with a timer or by the user tapping on it manually) over a UITabBar Item on the iPhone.

I've looked into the [WEPopover library](https://github.com/werner77/WEPopover) but it wasn't quite as helpful as I would have liked it to be for my use case.

I see mobile websites achieve my desired effect all the time but am interested in duplicating this functionality (albeit to use it less frequently than they seem to) in Cocoa Touch for a first-run sort of guide in an app.

[image: Example Image]

Anyone have any ideas I should explore in how to go about implementing this?

Comment: The screenshot is of a website opened in Safari, is this your scenario as well? In that case you will need to run javascript to display the popover.

Comment: Hi Danra, no, this is not my scenario. I have seen this functionality mostly on web-based things like my screenshot, but I'm interested in implementing it in Cocoa natively to work in tandem with a UITabBar.

Comment: Sorry, I was replying too quickly with my comment above. In the original question I absolutely state Cocoa Touch as I'm aware of the difference. Thank you though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's really no good answer to this, I don't think. You're going to have to implement your own UI, possibly in connection with a subclass of `UITabBar`, in order to achieve this. The actual popup UI probably exists in any number of third-party code, but you'd have to come up with your own system. A "simple" solution would be to place these popup views on the application window so they could appear atop all other UI elements. You'd also create a manager class to control presenting, dismissing, and timing these elements.